# Displaying typed text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to display text in an app for Android, but I am completely new to Android development. I know Java fairly well but, how would I display text in the middle of an app like if it were a texting app? I got a text field on the bottom with a <kbd>Send</kbd> button, but after they clicked <kbd>Send</kbd>, I want to be able to display what they typed in the middle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just add a new TextView and add to it each time the button is clicked.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I am very new to Android development(I just started 20 minutes ago.. )..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the layout that you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You don't necessarily need to set your onClick event in xml. Use the other answers as examples on how to add an onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Add a new TextView, XML is as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/new_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I am some new text!" />
```

This will just create a new TextView element, you will need to add new parameters to the XML to specify its position on the screen, all depending on what type of layout you are using.

If you were to add this element to your `Button`

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```

You could edit the text from your Activity, on button press, using the following code:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(){
        TextView newTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.new_text_view);
        EditText editMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        newTextView.setText(editMessage.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, so would I then need to create a method that adds what ever is typed when the send button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, you can reference this element in the Java code by using its ID, and edit the contained text. I will add the code above.

Comment: I edited my above code, which will now allow you to enter text in your EditText, and then click on the button you have to change the text inside of your new TextView to that of what you entered in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

edit your xml to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView ndroid:id="@+id/text_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
   android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
   />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in code write the follwing:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
            edit_message= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String text = edit_message.getText().toString();
            text_message= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_message);
            text_message.setText(text );
    }
 }
```

Comment: both parts. the xml is wrong, you should've tested that. and there is already an onClick set in the xml

Comment: well actually I don't, if I will test every answer I give here then i will be testing my answers all day and won't write any code. you right about the onClick method I didn't notice that. what's wrong with the second part?

Comment: You don't actually have to test it to know it's wrong, but you could simply make a new xml in any project, paste in the xml and check that the graphical layout looks correct. Not very hard at all

Comment: it's not hard at all, you right. but this was not the issue of the question.

Comment: It was the exact question. If he used your xml, it would not have worked. period. your answer is wrong. stop replying, your English is terrible.

Comment: @ElefantPhace, thank you for analyzing my English skills but I guess that we are not here for that either.